# Collection of employee objects to an array that contains only employee.id

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert a collection of employee objects to an array that contains only the employee's ID?

The collection would contain say:

```
e.id = 1;
e.name = a;

e1.id = 2
e1.name = b;
```

I would like to retrieve a list or array that contains only `employee.id` using LINQ.

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid calls to .ToList(), .ToArray(), .ToDictionary() etc. unless you're sure you really need it.  In the majority of cases you can just leave it as an enumerable.

Comment: @Servy: It depends. If the enumerable hits a database every time it's enumerated over, well, you'll wish that you just called `ToArray`. Or if it embeds and expensive calculation in some projection. Etc. Saying "you should avoid" without these caveat is dangerous. I don't even know if it's fair to say "in the majority of cases."

Comment: @Jason I guess I'll rephrase.  First off, the OP hasn't actually given enough information to state which is better in his case.  I merely brought up the point so that he would think about it.  In general though, I see lots of cases where people use .ToArray/.ToList when they don't need to, and I almost never see people not using it when they should.  As long as the OP takes the time to think about whether or not it is appropriate to call .ToArray then I'll consider my comment a success.

Answer (score 3):

```
var employeeIds = employees.Select(x => x.id).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> ids = employees.Select(a => a.id).ToList();
```

or

```
int[] ids = employees.Select(a => a.id).ToArray();
```

Comment: Could be. The question said "a list or array". I just wrote the first that came to mind. I'll modify my answer to include both.

Answer (score 0):

without having more details of your actual code....

```
  MyListOfEmployees.Select(e => e.id).ToList();
```